# How to extend class inheritance to other functions

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance

I have the following classes:

```
class c0(object):
    def post_pred(self, ins):
        print("this is post_pred in c0")

class c1(c0):

    def __init__(self):
        print("this is class c1")

    def predict(self, ins):
        print("this is predict in c1")
        selfz.post_pred(0)

    def post_pred(self,ins):
        print("this is post_pred in c1")



class c2(c1):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("this is class c2")

    def predict(self, ins):
        super().predict(0)
        print("this is predict in c2")
        self.post_pred(0)

    def post_pred(self, ins):
        print("this is post_pred in c2")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sss = c2()

    sss.predict(2)
```

What I want to see is after I run this script, I see the following output:

```
this is class c1
this is class c2
this is predict in c1
this is post_pred in c1
this is predict in c2
this is post_pred in c2
```

But instead I see:

```
this is class c1
this is class c2
this is predict in c1
this is post_pred in c2
this is predict in c2
this is post_pred in c2
```

It seems that the inheritance doesn't extend to the `post_pred` function. I am just wondering what is the right way to achieve my goal.

Comment: Inheritance worked exactly as expected here. You call `c1`'s` `predict` (via `super` in `c2`'s `predict`), which turns around and calls `post_pred`, but the `self` received by `c1.predict` is still an instance of `c2`, so `c2`'s `post_pred` is called. The whole point of being able to overload `post_pred` is to make it so it behaves differently when called on a `c2` instance (whether or not the caller knows it's `c2`). What else would you expect it to do?

Comment: Forcing `c1.predict` to only call `c2.post_pred` is possible (change `self.post_pred(0)` to `c1.post_pred(self, 0)`), but it's intentionally breaking overloading.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes I understand the logic, but my goal is when I call a function in the parent class, it should call only other functions in the parent class as well. I don't how can I achieve this goal.

Comment: To provide the context, I am trying to make some adjustments after I get the prediction from some machine learning model. I created a default prediction model to handle the generic case, and a customized prediction model to add more operations after the generic post_pred step is done. It seems from your response that what I am doing here is not the most appropriate way. Are there better ways of coding it up?